# Detect a 1 to 0 transition in an input in Verilog

Tags: digital-logic, verilog, simulation, system-verilog, edge-detection

I'm practicing Verilog using the HDLBits website, and I am trying to solve this problem where I have been given a 32-bit wide input signal and I have to detect whenever a `1 to 0` transition occurs and set the corresponding output bit high until I receive a `reset` signal. If both the transition and the `reset` occur simultaneously, the `reset` takes precedence. The `reset` is a synchronous reset.

A sample waveform is attached below:

[image: Waveform]

My attempt at this problem was to find the AND of the input at the previous clock cycle and the negative of the input in the new clock cycle to set the bit where the 1 to 0 transition occurred. My logic:

Input (previous clock cycle): `10011001`

Input (next clock cycle): `01001010`

Negative of that input: `10110101`

AND of old input and new input: `10010001`

Verilog code:

```vhdl
module top_module (
    input clk,
    input reset,
    input [31:0] in,
    output [31:0] out
);
    reg [31:0]in_prev;
    always @(posedge clk) begin
        in_prev <= in;
        if(reset)
            out <= 32'b0;
        else
            out <= in_prev & ~in;
    end
endmodule
```

However, the console shows me that my code is wrong and there are mismatches in the waveform. Can anyone tell me why this is happening?

Mismatch waveforms:

[image: Mismatch1]
[image: Mismatch2]

Comment: You're not holding the output bits until the reset occurs. You're simply doing a fresh edge detection on every clock cycle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set an output bit *only if* a negative edge was seen on the input bit.  I find in clearer to create a dedicated combinational logic signal to show the negative edge detection (refer to signal `ne` in the code below).  I also find it easier to understand if I use a `for` loop to check each input bit when setting the output:

```
module top_module (
    input clk,
    input reset,
    input [31:0] in,
    output reg [31:0] out
);

    reg [31:0] in_prev;

    always @(posedge clk) begin
        in_prev <= in;
    end

    wire [31:0] ne = (~in) & in_prev;

    always @(posedge clk) begin
        if (reset) begin
            out <= 0;
        end else begin
            for (int i=0; i<32; i++) begin
                if (ne[i]) out[i] <= 1;
            end
        end
    end
endmodule
```

This code passes on [HDLBits](https://hdlbits.01xz.net/wiki/Edgecapture).

Here is how your code behaves (in a pseudocode example):

On the positive edge of the clock, if reset is low:

```
 if (in=0 and in_prev=1) then set out = 1
 otherwise, set out = 0
```

It is the `otherwise` clause that causes the problem in your code.

Comment: I changed my code based on the suggestion made by @dave-tweed, I set the `else` condition as `out <= out | (in_prev & ~in)` so that the output bits are being held until the `reset` occurs and this passed on HDLbits. Is this a good method to go about implementing such a logic or do I have to use a `for` loop for this purpose just for the sake of best practice?

Comment: @Socks: In this case, it is a matter of preference.  Use whatever coding style is easier for you to understand.